# :Missing matching tag for <lightning-record-view-form> this lWC getting error i don't know what's wrong

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

```
                      <lightning-accordion-section name="ProductDetails" label="Product details ">

            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="SKU_Name__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Product_Specialist__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Ref_Lot_No__c"></lightning-output-field><br>
                    

                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Product_Category_Head__c"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Manufactured_In__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-accordion-section>

        <lightning-accordion-section name="DetailsofDealer/Userwhoisraisingthecomplaint" label="Details of Dealer/User who is raising the complaint "></lightning-accordion-section>
            
           
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Dealer_Name__c"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Address__c"></lightning-output-field>
                 </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Country_Codes__c"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Registered_Mobile_Number__c"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="WSS_Names__c"></lightning-output-field>
                </div>

            </div>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
            
        <lightning-accordion-section name="ComplaintDetails" label="Complaint Details">
            
            <template if:true={showWhy}>
                <template if:true={showOthers}>
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Nature_of_complaints__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Description__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Complaint_Sample_Availability__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Others__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">

                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Sub_Category_Defect__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Why__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>

                </div>
                </div>
                </template>
            </template>
        </lightning-accordion-section>

        <lightning-accordion-section name="SiteVisitReport" label="Site Visit Report">

                <template if:false={showSubCat}>

            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Name_of_the_Applicator_Contractor__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Area_in_sqft__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Observation__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">

                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Stage_of_application_during_complaint__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Application_Surface__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>

                </div>
                </div><hr>
                </template>
            </lightning-accordion-section>

                 <lightning-accordion-section name="CommercialSettlement" label="Commercial Settlement">

                 
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
                        <lightning-output-field field-name="Required__c"></lightning-output-field>
                        <lightning-output-field field-name="Quantity__c"></lightning-output-field>            
                     </div> 
                     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">

                        <lightning-output-field field-name="Primary_Invoice_No__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                        <lightning-output-field field-name="UOM__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>

                  </div> 
                </div>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                   </lightning-accordion>
              </lightning-record-view-form>                
          </div>
        </lightning-card>
```

Comment: Such trivial issue can be solved by following proper indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many issue is that you have prematurely terminated the `lightning-accordion-section` that is extra:

```
<lightning-accordion-section name="DetailsofDealer/Userwhoisraisingthecomplaint" label="Details of Dealer/User who is raising the complaint "></lightning-accordion-section>
```

Format your code properly to avoid such issues, [prettier](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier) plugin would comes in handy.